In need of help with step in proof of Lundberg inequality
I am looking over a proof of the Lundberg inequality. With the assumption of the renewal model, Net Profit condition (NPC), and existence of adjustment coefficient $r$, then it holds that
$$\psi(u)=P\left(\sup_{k\geq 1} S_k>u\right)\leq e^-{ru}$$
where $S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k X_i-cW_i$, $(X_i)$ is an iid claim size sequence, $(W_i)$ is an iid positive inter-arrival sequence, $c$ is some positive premium rate, and $u>0$ is the initial capital.
The trouble is with showing a step in the beginning - the rest follows easily from induction. The proof starts as follows:
Define
$$ \psi_n(u)=P\left(\max_{k\in[0,n]}S_k>u\right)$$.
The book, without proof, states $\psi_n(u)\uparrow \psi(u), n\to\infty$ which means that we only need to show $\psi_n(u)\leq e^-{ru}$. The problem is, I don't quite know if my proof of the statement is correct:
Let $$Y_n=1_{\max_{k\in[0,n]}S_k>u}, Y=1_{\sup_{k\geq1}S_k>u}$$
We have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n=Y$ and $|Y_n|\leq 1, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then by Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\psi_n(u)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\max_{k\in[0,n]}S_k>u\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_n\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(Y\right)=\psi(u)
$$
Firstly, is the proof of the statement correct?
Secondly, is is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n=Y$?

yes correct. You can also apply monotone convergence theorem since $0\leq Y_{n}\uparrow Y$. It also follows from continuity of measure too (which is proven by MCT) since
$$\{\max_{k\in[0,\infty)}S_k>u\}= \bigcup_{n} \{\max_{k\in[0,n]}S_k>u\} $$
and
$$P\left( \bigcup_{n} \{\max_{k\in[0,n]}S_k>u\}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\max_{k\in[0,n]}S_k>u).$$
